# In tinymce editor - when clicked in numberd list it's not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tinymce, tinymce-plugins

I won't be able to add bullet list or number list in tinymce editor  if any one know what wrong in my script.

I had add plugin like:

1. advlist
2. lists

but still it's not working,then what i have to do for start bullet and numbers list to be start properly

Here is my tinymce editor script code:

```
angular.module('ui.tinymce', [])
    .value('uiTinymceConfig', {
        theme: "modern",
        height: 1000,
        width: 1000,
        plugins: [
                 "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
                "searchreplace wordcount fullscreen ",
                "insertdatetime media table contextmenu directionality",
                "emoticons paste textcolor code"

        ],
        rel_list: [{ title: 'NoFollow', value: 'nofollow' }],
        menubar: 'edit insert view format table tools ',

        toolbar: "code|undo redo | fontselect fontsizeselect | forecolor backcolor |styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | print preview media | emoticons ",
        connector: 'https://www.qxas.co.uk/admin/Upload/index',

        templates: [
                { title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1' },
                { title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2' }

        ],
        formats: {
            bold : {inline : 'b' },  
            italic : {inline : 'i' },
            underline : {inline : 'u'}
        },

        extended_valid_elements: '*[*]',
        valid_children: "+body[style|script|link|rel],pre[script|div|p|br|span|img|style|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5],*[*]",
        valid_elements: '*[*]',
        force_p_newlines: false,
        cleanup: false,
        forced_root_block: false,
        //forced_root_block: 'P',
        content_css: "./assets/css/bootstrap.min.css,./assets/css/custom.css",
        convert_urls : 0,
        relative_urls: 'false',
        remove_script_host: 'true',
        document_base_url: 'https://www.qxas.co.uk/',
        plugin_preview_width: "2000",
        plugin_preview_height: "1000",
        valid_children: "+a[id|div|i|span|img|p|ul|ol|li|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h5|h6]"

    })
```

Answer (score 1):

This is tied to something in your `custom.css`.  I took your setup and make a TinyMCE Fiddle:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/p9gaab

If you just remove the custom.css from the `content_css` the list markers appear.  That CSS file is well over 1,000 lines so you will need to work through it to determine why this is happening.